# regex match variations of multiple words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have stored my value in a variable:

```
var myvalue = "hello bye";
var myText = "hellobye is here and hello-bye here and hello.bye"
```

how can I check if the variations of `myvalue` appears in the text?

i am using this pattern:

```
hello[-. ]*?bye
```

but i can't break my variable value like this. One more thing, what if my value contains more than two elements? like `hello bye hi`

Comment: your solution works fine for me: https://regex101.com/r/4y3A2Y/1

Comment: Can you please point out where is your problem? Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/mLkm9xph/). Is this the thing you wanne do?

Comment: Are you looking for **all** possible combinations here?

Comment: Replace all whitespace chunks with `[-.\\s]*?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace all whitespace chunks (match them with a mere `/\s+/g`) with `[-.\\s]*?` to create a regex to match the variations of `myvalue`:

```js
var myvalue = "hello bye";
var myText = "hellobye is here and hello-bye here and hello.bye"
console.log(myText.match(new RegExp(myvalue.replace(/\s+/g, '[-.\\s]*?'), 'g')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you are after. If you want an explanation, leave a comment and I will do my best.

```
var myvalue = "hello bye";
var searchReg = new RegExp('(' + myvalue.replace(/ /g, ')[-. ]*?(') + ')', 'g');
console.log(searchReg.source);
//-> (hello)[-. ]*?(bye)
var myText = "hellobye is here and hello-bye here and hello.bye";

console.log(myText.replace(searchReg, '$1^^^^^$2'));
// -> hello^^^^^bye is here and hello^^^^^bye here and hello^^^^^bye
```

If you don't need back references, it's a little easier to read:

```
var searchReg = new RegExp(myvalue.replace(/ /g, '[-. ]*?'), 'g');
```